# Recompile .java file without access to the libraries?

Tags: java, recompile

So here's my situation: I have a .jar file with 2 .class files in it, both import from a library I do not have access to (the library is proprietary and somehow hidden, so no way of getting it).

Now I'd like to change the implementation of these .class files. Decompiling is no problem, however since I don't have the libraries the code depends on I cannot compile. I have heard of creating "stubs" for the missing methods, but I don't know enough about java to figure out how to create such stubs in this case (if that is even possible some pointers in the right direction would be appreciated).

Is there some way I can make my modified files compile? Like forcing the compiler to ignore the missing methods? Or is my only option something like a [Java Bytecode Editor](http://set.ee/jbe/)?

Comment: if you don't have access to libraries it depends on, how do you use it in runtime ?

Comment: You don't have to have the source for the libraries, just the .class files.  And you can't run your app without those, so which is it?

Comment: The .jar will be used by a program written by the owner of the proprietary classes, meaning it probably has access to those libraries. However unfortunately I was unable to find them in the program's folders, I assume they are somewhere packed up in the program's files and then get unpacked at runtime to run the .jar file.

Comment: How do I find them? All I have is a vague assumption that they are somewhere, I'm not even sure they are packed up in the application itself. They could just aswell have been hidden somewhere on my system by the installer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a decompile class uses some missing dependency eg

```
class X {
  void x() {
      y.Y y = new y.Y();
      y.y();
  }
}
```

you should create a stub for it

```
package y;
public class Y {
    public void y() {
    }
}
```

Comment: My decompiled file contains imports like `import xxx.yyy.zzz;` How would I make a stub .class/.jar for something like that?

Comment: make directory structure xxx/yyy/zzz. Btw it is easy to create stubs using IDE, eg Eclipse has quick-fix feature which creates missing classes / methods automatically

Comment: Figured out the structure thing myself in the meantime. I wasn't compiling with a `-d` parameter, so my packages weren't being put in the right directory structure. Thanks anyways. Also I will have to look into using Eclipse more, so far command line is serving me well.

Comment: After around an hour of manually stubbing everything my files finally compiled and my modified code seems to be working so far, accepted and +1!